# how to delete firebase realtime database child node with key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, web, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to run the code below I get an error and I'm not sure why.

```
confirmDelete(e) {
  const db = getDatabase();
  db.ref("/ships/" + e.target.id).remove();
},
```

If I log the `e.target.id` I get the exact same as the **shipKey** in the code below.

Here's an example of what that database looks like:

```
{
  "ships": {
    "-N43Q4E2ruMpyfaIHGDK": {
      "date": "2022-08-06T18:00",
      "name": "ORANGE OCEAN",
      "shipKey": "-N43Q4E2ruMpyfaIHGDK"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using Firebase Modular SDK (V9.0.0+) where both `ref()` and `remove()` are top-level functions. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
// import the functions
import { getDatabase, ref, remove } from "firebase/database";

confirmDelete(e) {
  const db = getDatabase();
 
  // create DatabaseReference
  const dbRef = ref(db, "/ships/" + e.target.id);

  remove(dbRef).then(() => console.log("Deleted"))
},
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data) to learn more about the new syntax.

Comment: Thanks, @Dharmaraj.

I hadn't notice i had to use remove() first.

I also had to reference the database on your code that you forgot but it was simple detail stuff. you actually helped a lot.

Here's the working code:

`confirmDelete(e) {
      const db = getDatabase();
      // create DatabaseReference
      const dbRef = ref(db,"/ships/" + e.target.id);
      remove(dbRef);
    },`